# creating Outlook App which should run on machines in which outlook is not installed

Tags: .net, outlook-2010

I have developed an application which creates an outlook application using outlook object model. But I need this application to run on machines in which outlook is not installed.
I have refered the below link...
[Why doesn't the office PIA install correctly to the GAC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070124/why-doesnt-the-the-office-pia-install-correctly-to-the-gac)

where it is mentioned that copying the dll works.
I would like to know the login information for the outlook.
In my App,I have to get the details from outlook.
Does any one have an idea of running an App which retreives the information from outlook on the machines in which outlook is not installed? If so, does it requires any credentials and how to pass them?

Comment: This is not possible. You need to have Outlook installed in order to interact with Outlook. Any hack that you come up with will be ugly, broken, and thoroughly unsupported. Why would you expect this to work? Don't create an Outlook application if you don't want a dependency on Outlook.

Comment: But in the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070124/why-doesnt-the-the-office-pia-install-correctly-to-the-gac           "the PIAs could specifically be used for developing without Office being installed, so it would not make sense to have Office as a prerequisite." what about this info?

Comment: Uhh, what you're quoting as fact from that question is actually *speculation* from the person who is asking the question. This is one of his possible explanatory theories. He doesn't know either, and is just as confused as you are. Careful with quoting things from questions as facts; focus on the *answers*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Outlook is not installed, there is no information to retrieve from the "not installed" outlook.

So, do a check in your software:
*) if outlook is installed, retrieve the information
*) if outlook is not installed, return "no information" (as if outlook is installed, but doesn't contains any information)